# Inverse Laplace Transform of $\dfrac{1}{s^a+b}$

Tags: inverse-laplace

I could not find on tables, but trying some values I think that is something with $ ERFC$ functions.

I am seeking for a general formula to the inverse Laplace transform of $\dfrac{1}{s^a+b},$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive.

Someone know this formula?

Thank you so much.

==========

Please, see comments. Do you have any ideas to show at least that the inverse is positive? Thank you!

Comment: Can you do $1/(s+b)$ and $1/(s^2+b)$ ?

Comment: @GEdgar, yes, $e^{-b t}$ and $\sin(\sqrt{b} t)/\sqrt{b}$... Thank you

Comment: Maple cannot do $1/(s^{1/3}+1)$

Comment: @GEdgar, really, Wolfram neither... So maybe there's no formula for this...

Comment: @GEdgar would you have any ideas to show at least that the inverse is positive? thank you!

Comment: Expand $1/(s^a + 1)$ into a geometric series and take the ILT termwise. You'll get $t^{a - 1}$ times the Mittag-Leffler $E_{a, a}$ function (or a Fox-Wright function).

Comment: See table C.2 on page 209, https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9781119393351.app3

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk perfect, thank you so much!

Comment: @Maxim perfect, thank you so much also!